# Python - Is it possible to get the library Pyoptools for optical systems

Tags: python, installation, libraries

I am trying to find out if it is possible to (and how to) install (on windows) the Python library PyOpTools which is for modeling optical systems.

I have tried using Python's PIP function to find and install it but it can't find a module named pyoptools.

If PyOpTools is no longer freely available are there any other open source python libraries for ray tracing that people could recommend?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Installing directly on Windows

The pyOpTools code is still freely available on GitHub (and archived at Google Code).

Here is my **failed** attempt at installing pyOpTools directly on Windows (but see below for an alternative). Install Python 2.7, then in cmd.exe:

1. Install Cython, a pyOpTools dependency

   ```
   python -m pip install cython
   ```
2. Get and install Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266
3. Download pyOpTools from https://github.com/ramezquitao/pyoptools, using the Download ZIP button to, say, C:\Users\yourusername and unzip. Alternatively, get Git for Windows and clone.
4. Change into the pyOpTools directory containing setup.py and install pyOpTools

   ```
   python setup.py install
   ```

This fails with "fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals", but would have worked on Linux (presumably because it uses gcc). There may be a way to fix this but I don't know it. I am guessing pyOpTools is intended to also work on non-Unix systems since there is a comment to that effect in setup.py.

### Workaround: Virtual machine

My workaround is to run pyOpTools in a guest Ubuntu VM in VirtualBox and it works like a charm. If I need to access it from the Windows host, I use commands like VBoxManage guestcontrol. For an easy install method see code.google.com/p/pyoptools/wiki/Downloads, which has an Ubuntu ISO all ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

The pyoptools developers were recently successful in installing on Windows, with the help of Cygwin.

For the details see the Windows (using Cygwin) section in https://github.com/cihologramas/pyoptools/blob/master/README.md